# Cant find the path to local json file, C++

Tags: c++, boost, filepath

I have following C++ code:

{

```
boost::property_tree::ptree propTree;
auto module = GetModuleHandleW(nullptr);
WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleHandleW(module, path, MAX_PATH); 

// path above is same as the directory in which following config.json is present - I can see that in 
// debugger.

read_json("config.json", propTree);
```

}

so basically my application(exe) is running from the same directory as the json file. still it cant seem to find the json file. The exe finds the json just fine if I provide absolute/full path.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `GetModuleHandleW` doesn't take three parameters.

Comment: `"config.json"` is a file name relative to the current working directory, which may not be the same as the directory in which the EXE is located. If you want to see what the current directory is, use `GetCurrentDirectory`. If you want to locate a file in the directory next to the EXE, use `GetModuleFileName` to obtain the full path to the EXE, and replace the file name in it.